# restrict access to a especific wordpress page with facebook login

Tags: php, facebook, wordpress

I have a page with some sensitive content on a page and I want to restrict access to that page by asking the visitors to check their real ages.

I was thinking that the best way was to create a facebook app with age restrictions, and ask them to like the page (on facebook) or something... But I have no clue on how to implement this (besides creating the app) on wordpress.

Just to clear things out: My blog doesn't have register or login enabled.

Can someone give-me an hint?

Comment: If you have no clue, then just add an intermediate page asking them to verify their age with simple JS. The approach you though of requires a lot of effort to get it done.

Comment: not quite a solution because there they can fill it with false details...

Answer (score 0):

1st you can use a membership plugin for restricted a page from guest user. So, only logged in user can view this page.

2nd now setup/enable login with facebook in your wordpress site using a plugin.

That's it. I think its work for you.

Search here your plugin: http://wordpress.org/plugins/

Comment: ...problem is that I don't wish to enable the register function. And I also can't find a pugin that restricts the page by doing something similar...

Comment: are you tried  [Page Restrict](http://wordpress.org/plugins/pagerestrict/) or  [advanced access manager](http://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-access-manager/) for restrict a page/post?